# making to fit a table in LNCS page style

Tags: tables, lncs

This is my table skeleton

[image: output_example]

which I have problem to make it to fit in a LNCS style page, especially the headers (2 first rows) as they contain text and the other cells inside the table contain only one symbol per cell, e.g. "+".

Any help how I can solve it? I do not need for the lines, sure. I am using the `booktabs` package.

### Edit 1:

Some of my code is:

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}


\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}

\usepackage{multirow}
% end: for table

%begin: for landscape table
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lscape}
%end: for landscape table

\usepackage{xspace}

\newcommand{\bs}{$\blacksquare$ \xspace}
\newcommand{\sr}{$\square$ \xspace}
\newcommand{\lt}{$\blacktriangleleft$ \xspace}



\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[]
%\centering
\small
\caption{Something which is moving my table too down}
\label{my-label}
\hskip-3.0cm \vskip-2.0cm \begin{tabular}{@{}p{4cm}p{0.6cm}p{0.6cm}p{0.6cm}p{0.6cm}p{0.6cm}p{0.6cm}p{0.6cm}p{0.6cm}p{0.6cm}p{0.6cm}p{0.6cm}p{0.6cm}p{0.6cm}p{0.6cm}p{0.6cm}p{0.6cm}p{0.6cm}p{0.6cm}p{0.6cm}p{0.6cm}p{0.6cm}p{0.6cm}p{0.6cm}p{0.6cm}@{}}
\toprule
{\color[HTML]{009901}{} } & \multicolumn{3}{l}{{\color[HTML]{009901}{{}} }} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{{\color[HTML]{009901}{\rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{}} }} & {\color[HTML]{009901}{\rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{}} } & {\color[HTML]{009901}{\rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{}} } & \multicolumn{2}{l}{{\color[HTML]{009901}{\rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{}} }} & \multicolumn{3}{l}{{\color[HTML]{009901}{\rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{}} }} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{{\color[HTML]{009901}{\rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{}} }} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{{\color[HTML]{009901}{\rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{}} }} & {\color[HTML]{009901}{\rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{}} } & {\color[HTML]{009901}{\rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{}} } & {\color[HTML]{009901}{\rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{}} } & {\color[HTML]{009901}{\rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{}} } & {\color[HTML]{009901}{\rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{}} } & {\color[HTML]{009901}{\rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{}} } & {\color[HTML]{009901}{\rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{}} } & {\color[HTML]{009901}{\rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{}} } \\ \midrule

{\color[HTML]{009901} \textit{}} & {\color[HTML]{009901} {\rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{\textit{}}}} & {\color[HTML]{009901} {\rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{\textit{}}}} & {\color[HTML]{009901} {\rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{\textit{}}}} & {\color[HTML]{009901} \textit{}} & {\color[HTML]{009901} \textit{}} & {\color[HTML]{009901} \textit{}} & {\color[HTML]{009901} \textit{}} & {\color[HTML]{009901} \textit{}} & {\color[HTML]{009901} \textit{}} & {\color[HTML]{009901} \textit{}} & {\color[HTML]{009901} \textit{}} & {\color[HTML]{009901} \textit{}} & {\color[HTML]{009901} \textit{}} & {\color[HTML]{009901} \textit{}} & {\color[HTML]{009901} \textit{}} & {\color[HTML]{009901} \textit{}} & {\color[HTML]{009901} \textit{}} & {\color[HTML]{009901} \textit{}} & {\color[HTML]{009901} \textit{}} & {\color[HTML]{009901} \textit{}} & {\color[HTML]{009901} \textit{}} & {\color[HTML]{009901} \textit{}} & {\color[HTML]{009901} \textit{}} & {\color[HTML]{009901} \textit{}} \\

\multicolumn{3}{l}{\color[HTML]{34696D}{} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } \\

Something1 & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \bs & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & \sr & \bs & ao &  & A & \sr & \lt & \bs & \bs & \lt \\
Something2 & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \bs & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & \sr & \bs & ao &  & A & \sr & \lt & \bs & \bs & \lt \\
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\color[HTML]{34696D}{} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } \\
Something3 & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \bs & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & \sr & \bs & ao &  & A & \sr & \lt & \bs & \bs & \lt \\
 Something4 & \bs & \sr & \lt & \bs & \sr & \bs  & \sr & \bs & \sr & \bs & \bs & \bs & \sr & \bs & \bs & \sr & ind &  & I & \sr & \bs & \lt & \bs & \lt \\
 Something5 & \lt & \bs &  &  & \bs & \bs  & \lt & \sr & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & oo &  & A & \bs &  & \lt & \lt & \lt \\
Something6 & \bs & \lt & \lt & \bs & \bs & \bs &  & \bs & \bs & \bs & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & oo &  & E & \lt & \sr & \bs & \lt & \lt \\
 something7 & \bs & \bs & \lt & \bs & \bs & \bs & \bs & \sr & \bs & \bs & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & oo &  & E & \lt &  & \sr & \sr & \lt \\
 Something8 &  &  &  & \lt & \bs &  & \lt & \sr & \bs & \bs & \bs & \lt & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & oo &  & E &  & \sr & \bs & \bs & \lt \\
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\color[HTML]{34696D}{\textbf{Anotherthing}} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } \\
Something9 & \lt & \lt & \lt &  & \bs & \bs & \bs & \sr & \bs & \bs &  &  & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & oo &  & A & \bs & \sr &  &  &  \\
Something10 & \sr & \sr & \bs & \bs & \sr & \bs & \bs & \lt & \bs &  & \bs &  & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & pr &  & A & \bs & \sr & \lt & \lt & \lt \\
Something11 & \sr & \sr & \bs &  & \bs & \bs & \bs & \sr & \bs & \bs & \bs &  & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & oo &  & A & \lt & \sr & \bs & \bs & \bs \\
Something12 & \lt & \bs & \bs & \bs &  & \bs & \bs & \bs & \bs & \bs &  &  & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & ge &  & E & \bs & \sr & \lt & \bs & \lt \\
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\color[HTML]{34696D}{\textbf{Anotherthing2}} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } \\
 Something13 &\bs & \bs &  & \lt & \bs & \bs & \bs & \lt & \bs & \bs & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & oo &  & I/E & \bs & \sr & \bs & \bs & \lt \\
 Something14 & \bs & \sr & \bs & \lt & \bs & \bs & \bs & \sr & \bs & \bs & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & oo &  & E & \lt & \sr & \bs & \bs & \lt \\
 Something15 & \bs & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \bs & \bs & \sr & \bs & \bs & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & oo &  & E & \bs & \sr & \bs & \bs & \lt \\
 Something16 & \bs & \bs & \sr & \lt & \bs & \bs & \bs & \sr & \bs & \bs & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & oo &  & E & \bs & \sr & \bs & \bs & \lt \\
 Something17 & \lt & \sr & \bs & \lt & \bs & \bs & \bs & \sr & \bs & \bs & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & oo &  & E & \bs & \sr & \bs & \bs & \lt \\
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\color[HTML]{34696D}{\textbf{Anotherthing3}} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } & {\color[HTML]{34696D} } \\
 Something18 & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \bs & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & \sr & \bs & ao &  & A & \sr & \lt & \bs & \bs & \lt \\
Something19 & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \bs & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & \sr & \bs & ao &  & A & \sr & \lt & \bs & \bs & \lt \\
 Something20 & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \bs & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & \sr & \bs & ao &  & A & \sr & \lt & \bs & \bs & \lt \\
 Something21 & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \bs & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & \sr & \bs & ao &  & A & \sr & \lt & \bs & \bs & \lt \\
 Something22 & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \bs & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & \sr & \bs & ao &  & A & \sr & \lt & \bs & \bs & \lt \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

### Edit 2:

Changed header:
[image]

### Edit 3:

This is what is looking to me using the LNCS class:
[image]

Except that the page before become landscape and is blank the table itself is narrowed in the "text size" of a vertical alignment! Actually, I changed these three things from your solution:

1. I am using the LNCS class which is required
2. I removed the `\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}` because it's "destroying" the standard margins of the page something that I am not allowed to touch :(
3. I removed the `mathtools`  from `\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}` because for some reasons I cannot get that!

Comment: Nice sketch, however what is a problem in your code? Can you show your code which you made so far? For fit table to text width is usualy help to use `tabularx` or `tabular*` environments. where you declare desired table width.

Comment: @Zarko, I added my code till now ...and I think that I am not supposed to use `\hskip-3.0cm \vskip-2.0cm` :(

Comment: But your code is not complete ... I can't compile it. In it you use some  commands which are not defined. Please ad preamble to this table with all necessary packages as well with command definitions for `\bs`, `\lt` etc

Comment: @Zarko, I think you can compile it now, just take the llncs class. Some shown packages are not used here...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:** I think, that the `llncs` document class is not the first concern. Table is huge, so it need to be deliberately designed (shrink) ...

For table below I did the following:

- by defining colors by `newcolor` in document preamble the table code is significantly reduced
- by defining new commands:`\crb`, `\cit` and `mcit` also reduce the table code
- by changing column type `p{0.6cm}` to  `c` the width of table becomm smaller
- by eliminating of `xspace` the column become narrower and content is now in columns center.
- color for rows, which contains text `Another thing ...` is determined by `\rowcolor{...}` and text put in `\multicolumn{25}{l}{ ... text ...}`
- the float table is removed, for caption is used `captionof{table}{...}`. It works fine, so the manual positioning of table is not needed anymore
- the code partial consider your new column heads design. Since `\rotatebox` doesn't work well in `multirow` cells, the column heads are only in one row.
- for multiline cels in the first row is used `\stackon` macro from package `stackengine`

The complete code with only necessary packages is:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{array,amsmath,amssymb}% amsmath instal amsfonts
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}% instead of [left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
% my colors    
\definecolor[named]{mygreen}{HTML}{009901}
\definecolor[named]{myteal}{HTML}{34696D}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{stackengine}
%begin: for landscape table
    \usepackage{pdflscape}
    \usepackage{lscape}
%end: for landscape table
\newcommand{\bs}{$\blacksquare$}
\newcommand{\sr}{$\square$}
\newcommand{\lt}{$\blacktriangleleft$}
%new commands    
\newcommand{\crb}[1]{\rotatebox[origin=l]{90}{\itshape\textcolor{mygreen}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\cit}[1]{\textit{\textcolor{mygreen}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\mcit}[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{\textit{\textcolor{mygreen}{#2}}}}

    \begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
        \centering
        \small
\captionof{table}{Something which is moving my table too down}% Add 'table' caption
\label{my-label}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\begin{tabular}{l *{24}{c}}
    \toprule   
 & \mcit{3}{\stackon{align}{horizontal}}
   & \mcit{2}{\stackon{align}{horizontal}}
     & 
       & 
         & \mcit{2}{\stackon{align}{horizontal}}
 & \mcit{3}{\stackon{align}{horizontal}}
   & \mcit{2}{\stackon{align}{horizontal}}
     & \mcit{2}{\stackon{align}{horizontal}}
       & & & & & & &  
       \\
 \cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-6}\cmidrule(lr){9-10}%
 \cmidrule(lr){11-13}\cmidrule(lr){14-15}\cmidrule(lr){16-17}
 & \crb{vertical align}
   & \crb{align}
     & \crb{vertical}
       & \crb{vertical align}
         & \crb{vertical align}
           & \crb{vertical align}
 & \crb{vertical align}
   & \crb{vertical align}
     & \crb{vertical align}
       & \crb{vertical align}
         & \crb{vertical align}
           & \crb{vertical align}
 & \crb{vertical align}
   & \crb{vertical align}
     & \crb{vertical align}
       & \crb{vertical align}
         & \crb{vertical align}
           & \crb{vertical align}
 & \crb{vertical align}
   & \crb{vertical align}
     & \crb{vertical align}
       & \crb{vertical align}
         & \crb{vertical align}                                                
         \\
\rowcolor{myteal}
   \multicolumn{25}{l}{\color{white}\textbf{Another thing 3}} 
        \\
Something1 & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \bs & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & \sr & \bs & ao &  & A & \sr & \lt & \bs & \bs & \lt \\
Something2 & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \bs & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & \sr & \bs & ao &  & A & \sr & \lt & \bs & \bs & \lt \\
\rowcolor{myteal}
   \multicolumn{25}{l}{}                \\
Something3 & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \bs & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & \sr & \bs & ao &  & A & \sr & \lt & \bs & \bs & \lt \\
 Something4 & \bs & \sr & \lt & \bs & \sr & \bs  & \sr & \bs & \sr & \bs & \bs & \bs & \sr & \bs & \bs & \sr & ind &  & I & \sr & \bs & \lt & \bs & \lt \\
 Something5 & \lt & \bs &  &  & \bs & \bs  & \lt & \sr & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & oo &  & A & \bs &  & \lt & \lt & \lt \\
Something6 & \bs & \lt & \lt & \bs & \bs & \bs &  & \bs & \bs & \bs & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & oo &  & E & \lt & \sr & \bs & \lt & \lt \\
 something7 & \bs & \bs & \lt & \bs & \bs & \bs & \bs & \sr & \bs & \bs & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & oo &  & E & \lt &  & \sr & \sr & \lt \\
 Something8 &  &  &  & \lt & \bs &  & \lt & \sr & \bs & \bs & \bs & \lt & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & oo &  & E &  & \sr & \bs & \bs & \lt \\
\rowcolor{mygreen} 
   \multicolumn{25}{l}{\textbf{Another thing 1}}     \\
Something9 & \lt & \lt & \lt &  & \bs & \bs & \bs & \sr & \bs & \bs &  &  & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & oo &  & A & \bs & \sr &  &  & \\
Something10 & \sr & \sr & \bs & \bs & \sr & \bs & \bs & \lt & \bs &  & \bs &  & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & pr &  & A & \bs & \sr & \lt & \lt & \lt \\
Something11 & \sr & \sr & \bs &  & \bs & \bs & \bs & \sr & \bs & \bs & \bs &  & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & oo &  & A & \lt & \sr & \bs & \bs & \bs \\
Something12 & \lt & \bs & \bs & \bs &  & \bs & \bs & \bs & \bs & \bs &  &  & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & ge &  & E & \bs & \sr & \lt & \bs & \lt \\
\rowcolor{mygreen}
   \multicolumn{25}{l}{\textbf{Another thing 2}}     \\
 Something13 &\bs & \bs &  & \lt & \bs & \bs & \bs & \lt & \bs & \bs & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & oo &  & I/E & \bs & \sr & \bs & \bs & \lt \\
 Something14 & \bs & \sr & \bs & \lt & \bs & \bs & \bs & \sr & \bs & \bs & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & oo &  & E & \lt & \sr & \bs & \bs & \lt \\
 Something15 & \bs & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \bs & \bs & \sr & \bs & \bs & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & oo &  & E & \bs & \sr & \bs & \bs & \lt \\
 Something16 & \bs & \bs & \sr & \lt & \bs & \bs & \bs & \sr & \bs & \bs & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & oo &  & E & \bs & \sr & \bs & \bs & \lt \\
 Something17 & \lt & \sr & \bs & \lt & \bs & \bs & \bs & \sr & \bs & \bs & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & oo &  & E & \bs & \sr & \bs & \bs & \lt \\
\rowcolor{mygreen}
   \multicolumn{25}{l}{\textbf{Another thing 3}}     \\
 Something18 & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \bs & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & \sr & \bs & ao &  & A & \sr & \lt & \bs & \bs & \lt \\
Something19 & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \bs & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & \sr & \bs & ao &  & A & \sr & \lt & \bs & \bs & \lt \\
 Something20 & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \bs & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & \sr & \bs & ao &  & A & \sr & \lt & \bs & \bs & \lt \\
 Something21 & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \bs & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & \sr & \bs & ao &  & A & \sr & \lt & \bs & \bs & \lt \\
 Something22 & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \bs & \lt & \bs & \lt & \bs & \sr & \bs & \sr & \sr & \bs & ao &  & A & \sr & \lt & \bs & \bs & \lt \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{landscape}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: 1. Yes, I need the 19th column
2. Yes, they are in green, all my other small tables in the document have that color in header
3. Yes, it can be `\multicolumn{25}{1}{...}`

Comment: And:
4. It is close except that, in the first row you have merged the cells from column 9-18 and they shouldn't. Also, I wanted to "shrink" vertically the table through aligning the text horizontally in the first row where cells are merged and I have space (but for some reasons the text was expanding my fixed column size ! :( , to fit the whole text in one line). And, the cells that aren't merged in neither column 1 or 2 - I can merge them and to align the text vertically. `See Edit2`

Comment: @Valerin, see upgrade od my answer. In it I still not consider your ask in your comment. This ask is wuit demanding .. so, please help yourself and wrote code for the first row (without bothering how to make two line and  multi row cells).

Comment: using the `\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}` iit's changing the margins for the textual writing. When I am removing it the table moves too down in the page (and the last 3 rows doesn't fit at all). Anyway, I am going to try with your solution. Thanks for your great time!

Comment: in `Edit 3` is shown how it's looking like the solution using the LNCS class!!!

Comment: @Valerin, I upgrade my answer with some improvements of code, partial considering desired columns heads formatting. Now this should be final version of answer :-). Happy TeXing!

Comment: Can you change only the margins for the table and not the rest of the document? (\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry} changes it for all the document)